# Azure ML output from pipeline

Tags: python, azure, output, pipeline, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to construct a pipeline in Microsoft Azure having (for now) a simple python script in input.
The problem is that I cannot find my output.
In my Notebooks section I have constructed the following two codes:

1) script called "test.ipynb"

```
# azureml-core of version 1.0.72 or higher is required
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset, Datastore
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import math

#Upload datasets
subscription_id = 'myid'
resource_group = 'myrg'
workspace_name = 'mywn'
workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
dataset_zre = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='file1')
dataset_SLA = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='file2')
df_zre = dataset_zre.to_pandas_dataframe()
df_SLA = dataset_SLA.to_pandas_dataframe()
result = pd.concat([df_SLA,df_zre], sort=True)
result.to_csv(path_or_buf="/mnt/azmnt/code/Users/aniello.spiezia/outputs/output.csv",index=False)

def_data_store = workspace.get_default_datastore()
def_data_store.upload(src_dir = '/mnt/azmnt/code/Users/aniello.spiezia/outputs', target_path = '/mnt/azmnt/code/Users/aniello.spiezia/outputs', overwrite = True)

print("\nFinished!")
#End of the file
```

2) pipeline code called "pipeline.ipynb"

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import json
import azureml.core
from azureml.core import Workspace, Run, Experiment, Datastore
from azureml.core.compute import AmlCompute
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget
from azureml.core.runconfig import CondaDependencies, RunConfiguration
from azureml.core.runconfig import DEFAULT_CPU_IMAGE
from azureml.telemetry import set_diagnostics_collection
from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep
from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline, PipelineData, StepSequence
print("SDK Version:", azureml.core.VERSION)

###############################
ws = Workspace.from_config()
print('Workspace name: ' + ws.name, 
      'Subscription id: ' + ws.subscription_id, 
      'Resource group: ' + ws.resource_group, sep = '\n')
experiment_name =  'aml-pipeline-cicd' # choose a name for experiment
project_folder = '.' # project folder
experiment = Experiment(ws, experiment_name)
print("Location:", ws.location)
set_diagnostics_collection(send_diagnostics=True)

###############################
cd = CondaDependencies.create(pip_packages=["azureml-sdk==1.0.17", "azureml-train-automl==1.0.17", "pyculiarity", "pytictoc", "cryptography==2.5", "pandas"])
amlcompute_run_config = RunConfiguration(framework = "python", conda_dependencies = cd)
amlcompute_run_config.environment.docker.enabled = False
amlcompute_run_config.environment.docker.base_image = DEFAULT_CPU_IMAGE
amlcompute_run_config.environment.spark.precache_packages = False

###############################
aml_compute_target = "aml-compute"
try:
    aml_compute = AmlCompute(ws, aml_compute_target)
    print("found existing compute target.")
except:
    print("creating new compute target")

    provisioning_config = AmlCompute.provisioning_configuration(vm_size = "STANDARD_D2_V2", 
                                                                idle_seconds_before_scaledown=1800, 
                                                                min_nodes = 0, 
                                                                max_nodes = 4)
    aml_compute = ComputeTarget.create(ws, aml_compute_target, provisioning_config)
    aml_compute.wait_for_completion(show_output=True, min_node_count=None, timeout_in_minutes=20)
print("Azure Machine Learning Compute attached")

###############################
def_data_store = ws.get_default_datastore()
def_blob_store = Datastore(ws, "workspaceblobstore")
print("Blobstore's name: {}".format(def_blob_store.name))
# Naming the intermediate data as anomaly data and assigning it to a variable
output_data = PipelineData("output_data", datastore = def_blob_store)
print("output_data object created")
step = PythonScriptStep(name = "test",
                        script_name = "test.ipynb",
                        compute_target = aml_compute, 
                        source_directory = project_folder,
                        allow_reuse = True,
                        runconfig = amlcompute_run_config)
print("Step created.")

###############################
steps = [step]
print("Step lists created")
pipeline = Pipeline(workspace = ws, steps = steps)
print ("Pipeline is built")
pipeline.validate()
print("Pipeline validation complete")
pipeline_run = experiment.submit(pipeline)
print("Pipeline is submitted for execution")
pipeline_run.wait_for_completion(show_output = False)
print("Pipeline run completed")

###############################
def_data_store.download(target_path = '.',
                        prefix = 'outputs',
                        show_progress = True,
                        overwrite = True)
model_fname = 'output.csv'
model_path = os.path.join("outputs", model_fname)
pipeline_run.upload_file(name = model_path, path_or_stream = model_path)
print('Uploaded the model {} to experiment {}'.format(model_fname, pipeline_run.experiment.name))
```

And this give me the following error:

```
Pipeline run completed
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-a8a523969bb3> in <module>
    111 
    112 # Upload the model file explicitly into artifacts (for CI/CD)
--> 113 pipeline_run.upload_file(name = model_path, path_or_stream = model_path)
    114 print('Uploaded the model {} to experiment {}'.format(model_fname, pipeline_run.experiment.name))
    115 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/run.py in wrapped(self, *args, **kwargs)
     47                                      "therefore, the {} cannot upload files, or log file backed metrics.".format(
     48                                          self, self.__class__.__name__))
---> 49         return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
     50     return wrapped
     51 

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/core/run.py in upload_file(self, name, path_or_stream)
   1749         :rtype: azure.storage.blob.models.ResourceProperties
   1750         """
-> 1751         return self._client.artifacts.upload_artifact(path_or_stream, RUN_ORIGIN, self._container, name)
   1752 
   1753     @_check_for_data_container_id

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/artifacts_client.py in upload_artifact(self, artifact, *args, **kwargs)
    108         if isinstance(artifact, str):
    109             self._logger.debug("Uploading path artifact")
--> 110             return self.upload_artifact_from_path(artifact, *args, **kwargs)
    111         elif isinstance(artifact, IOBase):
    112             self._logger.debug("Uploading io artifact")

/anaconda/envs/azureml_py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azureml/_restclient/artifacts_client.py in upload_artifact_from_path(self, path, *args, **kwargs)
    100         path = os.path.normpath(path)
    101         path = os.path.abspath(path)
--> 102         with open(path, "rb") as stream:
    103             return self.upload_artifact_from_stream(stream, *args, **kwargs)
    104 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/azmnt/code/Users/aniello.spiezia/outputs/output.csv'
```

Do you know what the problem could be?
In particular I am interested in saving somewhere the output file called "output.csv"

Answer (score 5):

The best way for you to do this depends a bit on how you want to process the output.csv file after the run completed. But, in general you can just write your csv to the ./outputs folder:

```
# azureml-core of version 1.0.72 or higher is required
from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset, Datastore
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import math

#Upload datasets
subscription_id = 'myid'
resource_group = 'myrg'
workspace_name = 'mywn'
workspace = Workspace(subscription_id, resource_group, workspace_name)
dataset_zre = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='file1')
dataset_SLA = Dataset.get_by_name(workspace, name='file2')
df_zre = dataset_zre.to_pandas_dataframe()
df_SLA = dataset_SLA.to_pandas_dataframe()
result = pd.concat([df_SLA,df_zre], sort=True)

if not os.path.isdir('outputs')
    os.mkdir('outputs')
result.to_csv('outputs/output.csv', index=False)

print("\nFinished!")
#End of the file
```

After the run has completed, AzureML will upload the contents of the outputs directory to the run history, so no need to `datastore.upload()`.

Afterwards, you can see the file in http://ml.azure.com when you navigate to the run like my `model.pt` file below:
[image]

See here for some information on the ./outputs and ./logs folders: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-save-write-experiment-files#where-to-write-files

If you actually want to create another DataSet as a result of your Run, please see this post here: [Azure Machine Learning Service - dataset API question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59144503/azure-machine-learning-service-dataset-api-question/59166458#59166458)

Comment: Dear Daniel, thanks a lot for your aswer. I have changed the test.ipynb file as you suggested and then I went back on the pipeline.ipynb file and push the button "Run". The pipeline started to run, but no file in output is produced and I have exactly the same error as before, i.e. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/azmnt/code/Users/aniello.spiezia/outputs/output.csv'` It seems to me that the pipeline is not running the test.ipynb script. How is that possible?

Comment: Hi @AnielloSpiezia, are you sure that you redeployed the pipeline? I seems unlikely that after removing the full path from the script, that it would still be searching for the same path -- are you maybe triggering an old published pipeline? After executing your script pipeline.ipynb, you should see a pipeline run show up in the experiment 'aml-pipeline-cicd'. There is no need to start it from the UX.
P.S.: I would recommend giving your scripts the extension .py -- .ipynb is normally used for Python Notebooks and using the wrong extension can lead to problems downstream.

Comment: Thank you for saving countless hours of my time! Why is this information not available in the current version (v2) of the documentation? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/?view=azureml-api-2

Answer (score 1):

In Daniel's example above, you would need to download the output from the run rather than the datastore in your pipeline.ipynb code.  Instead of calling def_data_store.download(), you would call pipeline_run.download('outputs/output.csv', '.').

Another option is to output your data using PipelineData.  PipelineData represents a named piece of output of a pipeline step, and is useful if you want to connect multiple steps together with inputs and outputs.  With PipelineData, you would need to pass the PipelineData object into PythonScriptStep when you declare your step (as part of arguments=[] and outputs=[]), and then have your script read the output path from the command-line arguments.

This notebook has examples of using PipelineData within a pipeline and downloading the outputs:  https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-with-data-dependency-steps.ipynb

And this blog post has details about how to handle this within your script (parsing the command-line arguments, creating the output directory, and writing the output file):  https://blog.x5ff.xyz/blog/ai-azureml-python-data-pipelines/